# Why do I lose the cascade window option on some DB?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Why do I lose the cascade window option on some DB?

Look at the difference below

[image]

as you see tile "Windows" is missing in the bottom one, both DB are MDB format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to file > access options > current Database, check overlapping DB

[image]